# Connect Flutter to SslStrem in C#

Tags: c#, flutter, dart, ssl, sslstream

I have this c# server using SslStream:

```
TcpListener Server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 13001);
Server.Start();
var client = Server.AcceptTcpClient();

var stream = client.GetStream();
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(stream, false);
var certificate = new X509Certificate2("server.pfx", "password");
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate, false, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls, false);

string text= string.empty;

do
{
byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
int bytesRead = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
Input += (Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
} while (!Input.EndsWith("<EOF>"));

string Return = "Sesrver's answer" + "<EOF>";

sslStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Return), 0, Return.Length);
```

Before using SslStream I used to connect this flutter client:

```
String _textBuilder = "";
  Socket socket = await Socket.connect(ipAddress, port, timeout: const Duration(seconds: 8));
  socket.listen((List<int> event) {
      _textBuilder += utf8.decode(event);
  });
  socket.add(utf8.encode("Some request text" + "<EOF>"));
  while (!_textBuilder.endsWith("<EOF>"))
  {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 50));
  }
```

Everything worked fine but now I don't know how to connect flutter to server. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I realized that **it is pointless to use clean TCP** when I can use http package where everything is already prepared for secured connections. So I started using the [flutter http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package.

For beginners like me, don't waste your time building own code for secured connections, if it is not required to use TCP, use package instead. Wish you good luck :)